# Redirect non-www to www with SEO-friendly query strings

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am trying to redirect my site from non-www to www. My site is at [http://www.alennuskoodit.us]. I try to make it so that all requests without www would be redirected to www. Normal stuff so far.

However, if I go to http://alennuskoodit.us I end up here: http://www.alennuskoodit.us/index.php?qstr=http://www.alennuskoodit.us

This is the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

# going to install folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/install/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/install/index.php [NE,R,L]

# going to Admin folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/admin/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/Admin/index.php [NE,R,L]

# working with client side
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?qstr=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

This is what I tried, which doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alennuskoodit.us [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.alennuskoodit.us/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

How could I redirect all queries to http://alennuskoodit.us to http://www.alennuskoodit.us so that I would not end up breaking the other rewrites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your new rule before all the other rules i.e

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alennuskoodit.us$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.alennuskoodit.us/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

#other rules here
```

and it should prevent the qstr= param

Answer (score 0):

Step1= You Must Use This Code In htaccess File To Preferred www Version:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.).YourDomain.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://www.YourDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Step2= You Must Setting Your Preferred Domain In Google WebMaster Tools :

Open up your webmaster tools and click “Settings” right below “Configuration”. To the right look for the “Preferred Domain” and select which domain you prefer With www Or Not.